# foreach returns only last item repeatedly in c sharp

Tags: c#

I have c sharp code which uses for each loop to print items in list.Code is below

```
    static bool Process_component_statement(List<Evl_component> components,
         Evl_statement s)
    {
        Debug.Assert(!(s.type == Evl_statement.Statement_type.ENDMODULE));
        State_Type state = State_Type.INIT;
        Evl_component comp = new Evl_component();
        Evl_pin pin = new Evl_pin();
        while(s.tokens.Count != 0 && (state != State_Type.DONE))
        {

            Evl_token t = s.tokens.First();
            s.tokens.Remove(s.tokens.First());
            //  branches here to compute state transitions
            if (state == State_Type.INIT)
            {
                if (t.type == Evl_token.Token_type.NAME)
                {
                    comp.type = t.str;
                    comp.name = "NONE";
                    state = State_Type.TYPE;
                }
            }
            else if (state == State_Type.TYPE)
            {
                if (t.type == Evl_token.Token_type.NAME)
                {
                    comp.name = t.str;
                    state = State_Type.NAME;
                }
                else if (t.str == "(")
                {
                    state = State_Type.PINS;
                }
            }
            else if (state == State_Type.NAME)
            {
                if (t.str == "(")
                {
                    state = State_Type.PINS;
                }
            }
            else if (state == State_Type.PINS)
            {
                if (t.type == Evl_token.Token_type.NAME)
                {
                    pin.name = t.str; pin.bus_msb = -1; pin.bus_lsb = -1;
                    state = State_Type.PIN_NAME;

                }
            }
            else if (state == State_Type.PIN_NAME)
            {
                if (t.str == ",")
                {
                    comp.pins.Add(pin);
                    state = State_Type.PINS;
                }
                else if (t.str == ")")
                {
                    comp.pins.Add(pin);
                    state = State_Type.PINS_DONE;
                }
            }
            else if (state == State_Type.PINS_DONE)
            {
                if (t.str == ";")
                {
                    state = State_Type.DONE;
                }
            }
            else if (state == State_Type.DONE)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Assert(false); // shouldn't reach here;
            }
        }
        components.Add(comp);
        if (s.tokens.Count != 0 || (state != State_Type.DONE))
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("something wrong with the statement");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and in main if i use input, output i see is repetition of only last element,seems only last element is adding in list and it is getting repeated in output.

```
component not NONE 3
pin in2 -1 -1
pin in2 -1 -1
pin in2 -1 -1
```

how can i get output which is like

```
component  not NONE 3
pin out -1 -1
pin in1 -1 -1
pin in2 -1 -1
```

Comment: You should use `while (tokens.Count > 0)` instead of `for (; tokens.Count != 0;)`

Comment: You should also just show the lines that are giving you trouble. That is a lot of code to read for what is likely a simple error

Comment: You've posted 165 lines of code. Please reduce this to a [mcve] having performed suitable diagnostic work to narrow down the problem. (I'd also strongly recommend reading up on and then following .NET naming conventions.)

Answer (score 1):

Change every bit of code that looks like:

```
comp.pins.Add(pin);
```

to:

```
comp.pins.Add(pin);
pin = new Evl_pin();
```

The problem with your code (as is) is that you add the same pin repeatedly. So the problem isn't that `output i see is repetition of only last element` - it is that your first, second, third element etc are all the same element. The above change should fix that.

Comment: yes your fix worked.Thanks.Lists in C++ work diff than c sharp.